# Как на php и mysql избрранное вещей сделать?

Tags: php, mysql

я создал таблицы users, post и ps.  users - пользователь, post - почты, ps - хранятся id users и post. Но проблема в том, что не знаю с помощью чего лучше сделать избранный на html

Comment: Сформируйте вопрос еще раз, не понятно что вы хотите. И для связи таблиц не нужны третья.  Если нужно просто выбрать лучшие посты добавьте там колонку и проверяйте по ней.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

сделайте таблицу favourites, в ней храните id users, id post.

когда пользователь c id захочет посмотреть свое избранное,

то делаем выборку из таблице favourites все записи с id users, получаем id post, 
далее делаем выборку в таблице post на основании id post из таблице favourites.

Comment: Делается джойн, а не две выборки подряд.